# How do I correctly add a scrollspy in my bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a scrollspy to a small personal site I am working on. So far I have the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Jon Snow</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <div id="my-nav">
        <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#work">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I tried adding a id and using jQuery script like this:

```
<script>
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#my-nav' });
</script>
```

But no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do so you should take the time to post an actual working example of the problem (HTML/CSS/JS) and if you're using fullpagejs as you've mentioned in previous posts this should be (most likely) done using that plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is as shown in the example here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target your nav menu like this:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-nav">
```

More in http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy.